# Google Images search mouseovers, how do they work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

Pretty straightforward: Google image search has this nice UI mechanic that pops a larger-scale image with info on mouseover.

[For example.](http://www.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1600&bih=1075&tbs=isch:1&sa=1&q=magnets&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

[Lookbook does this too.](http://lookbook.nu/look/1325453-24-11-Drapery)

What would be the easiest way to replicate this effect, and what tools should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a sample i just did in 30 mins similar to my old plugin

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Wjf7B/2/

it should be enough to get you started i hope. there are certain things i botched due to time

Comment: Fancy! Thank you - I'll start fiddling around with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would bet they're using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).  A lot of Google effects use this.

Comment: I was guessing it was probably a bit of JavaScript, but I couldn't find any decent information on similar-style effects.

Comment: @WednesdayWolf - Have you taken a look at JQuery? There certainly is an effect in there that does this

Comment: So you're basically asking,"Mouseover magnets, how do they work?"

Comment: this is doable - i have coded something similar for mootools 1.11 2 years ago -- check the the product scroller at the bottom here: http://www.webtogs.co.uk/Keen_Mens_Kelowna_WP_Lace_Shoes_102603.html - but it's not a straight forward grab, i am afraid. i have been meaning to make this a stand-alone plugin (the live version interacts with other elements and bits from the site) but little time means thats not likely to happen. it can be simplified and turned into a plugin that replicates the effect within an hour or so. i will post here if i get around to doing it...